# Removing a p tag based on a conditional jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, conditional-statements

I am creating a google like search application for fun and I am running into an issue.

So right now I am successfully getting the data I want back. And I am showing what I want as well. However, some of the results have undefined for some properties I have rendering. so the page renders them as undefined.

I am attempting to write a conditional that checks if the property is undefined for an individual object. I was able to successfully do this with an image, where if an object does not have an image property, I assign it a generic image. The issue I'm having now, is when an object does not find a particular property, I want to remove the

tag associated with displaying that property for that particular object. Yet what is happening is it is removing all the

tags with that class name.

```
 function render() {
  $.each(loadedBooks, function(index, book) {
    checkData();
    $('#results').prepend(
      "<hr><div id =" + book.id + " class = 'book'><li>" + "<p class='thumbnail'><img src=" + book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail + "></img></p>" +
      "<p class='title'>" + book.volumeInfo.title + "</p>" +
      "<p class ='subtitle'>" + book.volumeInfo.subtitle + "</p>" +
      "<p class='authors'>" + book.volumeInfo.authors + "</p></div>"
    );
  })
}

function checkData() {
  for (var i = 0; i < loadedBooks.length; i++) {
    if (typeof loadedBooks[i].volumeInfo.subtitle === "undefined") {
      $('.subtitle').remove('p');
    };
    if (!loadedBooks[i].volumeInfo.hasOwnProperty('imageLinks')) {
      loadedBooks[i].volumeInfo.imageLinks = {
        thumbnail: "http://i.imgur.com/sJ3CT4V.gif"
      }
    };

  }
}
```

I've been wracking my brain for the past two days trying to get this to work correctly. I had an implementation two days ago before I decided to start over that was successful (very similar tot he typeof above) that DID work, but I'm unsure what I am doing incorrect. Thank you

Comment: Firstly, is it going into that `if (typeof loadedBooks[i].volumeInfo.subtitle === "undefined")` statement? Check by adding a `console.log()` statement. If yes, then check what is`$('.subtitle')` returning by `console.log($'.subtitle');`

Comment: console logging ($'.subtitle') gives me an array of p.subtitle objects (representing each of the 'books' rendered) the ones that have a subtitle have inner html as some text, and the ones that do not have inner html as "undefined"

Comment: Perfect! Then can you check whether i-th element of that array is having text `undefined` in that `for loop`? If that is the case, then you can remove `<p>` of that i-th element of that array as mentioned in one of the answers.

Comment: Those that are undefined have undefined when I console log the text. Now, when I go and remove them, It does not remove all the undefined <p> tags. Any ideas? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Then might be the `if (typeof loadedBooks[i].volumeInfo.subtitle === "undefined")` statement is not catching all the elements which have `undefined` text

Answer (score 1):

`$('.subtitle')` returns an array of all elements with the class *subtitle*.
That's why in pure JavaScript we write:
`document.getElementsByClassName('...');` Element**s** *(pural)*. 
While `$('#subtitle')` would equal to:
 `document.getElementById('...');` Element *(singular)*. 
So all you need to do is specify which element you want to remove from that array.

replace:
`$('.subtitle')` with `$($('.subtitle')[i])`
or in better jQuery, use:
`$('.subtitle:eq('+i+')');` or `$('.subtitle:nth-of-type('+i+1+')');`

Comment: by adding $('.subtitle')[i] to the code above, i get a cannot read property remove of undefined.

Comment: that's could be cos there's no .subtitle element at all. The remove should be on the parent element. That you can select which one with the same index idea.

Comment: also. I forgot to re-encapsulate the $()[] with the jQuery creator. $(). read again. thanks

Comment: i totally see what you are saying. when i did $($('.subtitle')[i]) it removed some <p> with subtitle, but still some rendered undefined, or some with a subtitle property were removed. with $('.subtitle:eq(i)'), nothing happened. Could there be something in my logic that you can see that might be causing this?

Comment: first: I forgot to pass the parameter i `'+i+'` (updated answer). Second: you don't need the 'p' inside `$($('.subtitle')[i]).remove()` since there are no other non-p subtitles selected (but both logic work). Third: Why are you prepending book info instead of appending?

Comment: I am prepending because I want new searches to render before the old searches. So by doing:`if(typeof loadedBooks[i].volumeInfo.subtitle === 'undefined'){
  $('.subtitle:eq('+i+')').text("hey")
 };` The books where subtitle IS defined, is replaced with text hey. I changed the === to be !== and then the ones that were undefined had text replaced. Not really sure why the === undefined targeted defined books, But then i changed to remove() and it does not remove all the undefined subtitles, just a few. ???

Comment: your `checkData` function tests every possible book. So no need to call it n times in the $.each loop. Also, Even after you deleted something you would prepend a '.subtitle'. So: try calling `checkData();` after the `})` (outside of `$.each`)

Comment: Yeah, i moved it to before the each. This way I can assign a default img if there was no image property. I'm still unsure why it is not targeting all the undefined and is targeting some of the ones that have a defined

Comment: But placing it before the $.each. It will still add undefined inside $.each. Place it after the $.each!

Comment: Hm, ok. I realize I need to make a different function for the image conditional, when it is after the each if the image is undefined I get an error. No big deal.
However, can you help me understand why this
`   if(typeof loadedBooks[i].volumeInfo.subtitle !== "undefined"){
  $('.subtitle:eq('+i+')').remove()
 };` is removing the undefined ones when if i do === (which makes sense because i want to remove the ones that are undefined) does not? 
Also thank you for your help!!

Comment: have you tried to `console.log(typeof loadedBooks[i].volumeInfo.subtitle)`? maybe it's not returning undefined after all.

Comment: Nah, they console log undefined like they should. hm. 
What is weird is now, when I do a new search, it is not working for the new results. Hm.

Comment: I would have to see a fiddle of something to test it now.